# Catalyst::Plugin::StatusMessage across multiple 'app' servers

Tags: perl, catalyst, status-message

So I'm using [Catalyst::Plugin::StatusMessage](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst::Plugin::StatusMessage) in my Catalyst app. The only issue is that right now I have a load balancer with two app servers behind it, both running catalyst. Because of this, if a status message is set on one app server, and then the user is redirected and then the load balancer sends them to the second app server, the user won't see the status message because the status messages are local to the app servers. Is there anyway that I could share these status messages across app servers, so that I don't have to worry which server the load balancer sends them to? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your status messages are local to your app-servers, does that imply that `$c->session` is using FastMmap or File as its Session::Store? The same issues must apply to anything in the session, presumably?

Given that C::P::StatusMessage uses the session to manage its messages, you might have to change Session::Store to use a database-backed storage mechanism. There are [quite a few such options](https://metacpan.org/search?q=catalyst%3a%3aplugin%3a%3asession%3a%3astore), the most likely candidate being [Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::DBIC](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aSession%3a%3aStore%3a%3aDBIC)

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but this makes sense. Thanks!